# Python Class issue with calling function

Tags: python, class, curve-fitting

Hi I just start writing my first python class and I have an issue with this line `plsq=leastsq(lotzfit.residuals,self.p0,args=(self.y,self.x));`.  I can run it without using class. But with class, I am confused with variable. And now I keep getting error for that line.`TypeError: unbound method residuals() must be called with lotzfit instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)`. And I tried to put `plsq=leastsq(lotzfit.residuals(self),self.p0,args=(self.y,self.x));` but it also won't work. Here is the code. Btw, is it right to organize a file like this as a class or should I keep it as a general function.py instead of class? Thanks,

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy import average,max,sqrt,argmax
import numpy.random as npr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 6, 9

class lotzfit:
def __init__(self,x,y,p0):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.p0=p0

def mylotz(self):
    A,B,C,D=self.p0
    # """lorentz equation."""
    return (A/((self.x-B)**2+C)) + D

def residuals(self):
#"""Deviations of data from fitted 4PL curve"""
    err = self.y-lotzfit.mylotz(self)
    return err

def peval(self):
   # """Evaluated value at x with current parameters."""
    return lotzfit.mylotz(self)

def mylotzfit(self):

    plsq=leastsq(lotzfit.residuals,self.p0,args=(self.y,self.x));

    return plsq[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    plsq=leastsq(lotzfit.residuals,self.p0,args=(self.y,self.x));
```

to

```
    plsq=leastsq(self.residuals(), self.p0, args=(self.y,self.x))
```

Comment: I am still getting this error message `TypeError: unbound method residuals() must be called with lotzfit instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`. Here is how I use `test=lotzfit(x,y,p0)` and when I try `test.mylotzfit()` and I got error. Thanks,

Comment: @user3400793, use `self.residuals()` instead of `lotzfit.residuals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `lotzfit.residuals`, I'm pretty sure you want to be using `self.residuals`. This will give you a "bound" method, rather than an "unbound" one. In Python 2, an unbound method checks to make sure its first argument is an instance of the class it is defined in (in Python 3, this check is dropped and you just get the bare function).

That may not be enough to make the code work though. It looks like the function passed to [the `leastsq` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) needs to take an argument that is an array, and your `residuals` method doesn't take any arguments other than `self`.

There are a few other places you can do similar changes to my first point above. For instance, `lotzfit.mylotz(self)` is equivalent to `self.mylotz()` (and the latter is more idiomatic).

Answer (score 0):

You're making a slight error when calling your methods:

```
err = self.y-lotzfit.mylotz(self)

return lotzfit.mylotz(self)

plsq=leastsq(lotzfit.residuals,self.p0,args=(self.y,self.x));
```

In all of these, you're calling the method on the `class` object and not the instance of that class. They should instead be:

```
err = self.y-self.mylotz()

return self.mylotz()

plsq=leastsq(self.residuals, self.p0, args=(self.y,self.x)) # semi-colon not required!
```

Instance methods will automatically pass themselves into the method so you don't need to manually do it yourself.

You also seem to want to be passing the result of `residuals` into `leastsq` rather than method itself. You can either call the method when you're passing it in as an argument:

```
plsq=leastsq(self.residuals(), self.p0, args=(self.y,self.x))
```

Or you can make it a property, so the attribute lookup returns the result:

```
@property
def residuals(self):
    ....
```

I tend to prefer the property approach is a method doesn't take arguments and represents a value of the instance.

It's considered good practice to capitalise class names as well, and if you're using Python 2.x, you probably want to use a new class:

```
class Lotzfitz(object):
```

Comment: Thanks. I added this `plsq=leastsq(self.residuals,self.p0,args=(self.y,self.x))` and now it is giving me `TypeError: residuals() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)`. I defined like this  `plsq=leastsq(residuals,p0,args=(y,x));`in my non-class file. I would like to send 4 args to leastq not residuals.